# Error in MSR Identity toolkit (fopen)

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I try to run a demo for speaker verification using [MSR Identity toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52279). However it left error after training UBM step. The error is as follow. It looks like `fopen` return `-1` and cause error to `fread`. I can't understand why it can't read the `filenames`. I can't attach the code since it involves many functions. I just hope someone that familiar with this toolkit can help me.

```
Error using fread
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in htkread (line 7)
nframes = fread(fid, 1, 'int32'); % number of frames

Error in mapAdapt>load_data (line 107)
    data{ix} = htkread(filenames{ix});

Error in mapAdapt (line 52)
    dataList = load_data(dataList);

Error in demo_gmm_ubm (line 69)
    gmm_models{spk} = mapAdapt(spk_files, ubm, map_tau, config);
```

Part of the code where lead to the error as follow:

```
function data = load_data(datalist)
% load all data into memory
if ~iscellstr(datalist)
    fid = fopen(datalist, 'rt');
    filenames = textscan(fid, '%s');
    fclose(fid);
    filenames = filenames{1};
else
    filenames = datalist;
end
nfiles = size(filenames, 1);
data = cell(nfiles, 1);
for ix = 1 : nfiles,
    data{ix} = htkread(filenames{ix});
end

function [data, frate, feakind] = htkread(filename)
% read features with HTK format (uncompressed)
fid = fopen(filename, 'r','b'); %ERROR HERE
nframes = fread(fid, 1, 'int32'); % number of frames
frate   = fread(fid, 1, 'int32'); % frame rate in nano-seconds unit
nbytes  = fread(fid, 1, 'short'); % number of bytes per feature value
feakind = fread(fid, 1, 'short'); % 9 is USER
ndim = nbytes / 4; % feature dimension (4 bytes per value)
data = fread(fid, [ndim, nframes], 'float');
fclose(fid);
```

`datalist` contains:

```
'features\fadg0_sa2.htk'
'features\fadg0_si1279.htk'
'features\fadg0_si1909.htk'
'features\fadg0_si649.htk'
'features\fadg0_sx109.htk'
'features\fadg0_sx19.htk'
'features\fadg0_sx199.htk'
'features\fadg0_sx289.htk'
'features\fadg0_sx379.htk'
```

Comment: Did you generate files 'features\fadg0_sa2.htk'? I am looking to see demo with dummy speech data and I was not able to find in MSR toolbox. You know any setup which I can run directly?

Answer (score 0):

I use MSR Identity Toolkit without problem, fortunately.

What I have in htkread.m is as follows:

...

fid = fopen(filename, 'rb', 'ieee-be');

nframes = fread(fid, 1, 'int32'); % number of frames

...

Maybe the error you encountered comes from:

- big-endian/little-endian issue
- the *.htk feature you have is missing
- the *.htk is with other format

regards,

tommy

Comment: I try the big-/little-endian but it doesn't work too. I'll try to look into 2nd & 3rd issues you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Is your fid returning a negative value? If yes, try specifying entire path where dataList= 'ubm.lst'; is in the code