# Using writehtk for feature extraction (Speaker Identification)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am working on Speaker Identification and found [this post on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240357/matlab-code-for-a-lot-of-gaussian-mixture-model)  very useful.

Although the code is working fine, I just had a small doubt:

**Code given in answer**

```
fRate = 0.010 * fs; 
....
writehtk(featureFilename, mfc', 100000, 9);
```

**The function `writehtk` from Voicebox**

```
function writehtk(file,d,fp,tc)
%WRITEHTK write data in HTK format []=(FILE,D,FP,TC)
%
% Inputs:
%    FILE = name of file to write (no default extension)
%       D = data to write: one row per frame
%      FP = frame period in seconds
%      TC = type code = the sum of a data type and (optionally) one or more of the listed modifiers
```

The `writehtk` function needs the frame period in seconds, but in the code the unit is something else.

Could anyone please explain how this value is obtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little bit of confusion in the [post you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22308134/2994596).

The use of `fRate` as argument to [`melcepst`](https://github.com/covarep/covarep/blob/master/external/voicebox/melcepst.m) indicates that the author intended `fRate` to represent a 10ms interval (rather than the frame rate) between frames converted to a number of samples. This would also be consistent with the author's use of `100000` as `FP` argument had this argument been in units of 100ns (which is an incorrect attempt to perform a conversion that the [`writehtk` function already does internally](https://github.com/covarep/covarep/blame/master/external/voicebox/writehtk.m#L88)).

Personally I'd rename the variable `fRate` to `fInterval` to avoid confusion between rates (usually given in Hz) and time intervals (typically given in either seconds or number of samples when the sampling rate is also specified):

```
fInterval = 0.010 * fs; % in samples
...
mfc = melcepst(s, fs, '0dD', nCeps, nChan, fSize, fInterval, fL, fH);
```

Then the frame duration in seconds is simply 0.01, or given in terms of the previously defined variables `fInterval/fs`:

```
writehtk(featureFilename, mfc', fInterval/fs, 9);
```

Comment: Thanks SleuthEye! If the author's code has been directly used to write htk files, (considering the incorrect attempt to perform the conversion), will the htk files be produced correctly?

Comment: Mostly. The frame duration (`FP`) parameter is only written near the start of the htk file, with no impact on the saved coefficients.